# Tensor product of free and indecomposable modules over $K[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $K$, $M$ an $(A, K[t])$-bimodule that is free as a $K[t]$-module of rank $d$ and $N$ an irreducible left $K[t]$-module.

Why is the left $A$-module $M \otimes_{K[t]}N$ indecomposable?

I know that such $N$ is of the form $K[t]/(t-\lambda)$ for some $\lambda \in K$  and $M=\bigoplus_{i=1}^d m_i . K[t]$ for a basis $(m_1,\cdots,m_d)$, so that $M \otimes_{K[t]}N$ is $d$-dimensional as a vectorspace.
Hence it suffices to show that $\mathrm{End}_{A}(M \otimes_{K[t]}N)$ is local.

I'm not getting any further than that and hope you can help me.

Comment: Quick note: $N\cong K[t]/(t-\lambda)^n$ for some $\lambda\in K$ and $n\geq 0$. Are there any additional assumptions about $M$ as an $A$-module?

Comment: Thanks, I meant $N$ irreducible.

Comment: I think you must be missing some conditions on $M$. For example, take $A=K$ and $M=K[t]^d$. Then $M\otimes_{K[t]}N\cong K^d$, which is not indecomposable as a module for $A=K$.